# Displaying text in a window with PyQT4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am trying to make a GUI interface using PyQt4.  I want to be able to send text from my python program and have it be displayed on a window created by PyQt4.

I've been able to input data via a push button, but I would like to be able to write it from my python program.  I can create a window using the self.setGeometry command, and I am fairly sure that the functions I need for writing blocks of text are in the QTextEdit Module (not QLabel, because that's for 1-line sections of text).  The problem is that there are so many functions to use, and I'm new to PyQT (and Python in general, actually) so I don't understand the structure very well yet.  Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

QLabel is used to display texts while QTextEdit is mostly used to get one-line inputs of the user. e.g a form field to indicate that a name must be typed into the input area, QLabel is used as *Name :*  and the QTextEdit is where the user will type in.

But i think you should first check out layouts and placing methods on PyQt (Qt mostly) and then try create simple GUIs by hand so that'll make you learn basics and all other great tools of Qt, easily.

There is also tool called Qt Designer which is very handy to creat GUIs for PyQt ( & Qt) programs by drag & drop tools.